# Dead wi-fi receiver on laptop, is there a product to receive a wi-fi signal and convert to wire signal?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, dongle

Wi-fi on my laptop (Dell) computer died after being flaky for a few months.  My computer is out of warranty.  There must be an external device that is a wi-fi transceiver that converts to/from a wire signal so that I could plug into the ethernet port as if on an ethernet cable connection.  Does such a product exist?  What is it called?

Thanks!

Comment: they make wifi usb devices.

Answer (score 5):

Get a USB wifi connector for 10 $ or replace the card inside your laptop for the same price.

Any external device would be much more expensive, need a power supply, etc.

But in the spirit of your question, yes, they exist. You can configure most wireless router as Repeater, and use the ethernet ports on its back.

Comment: So a "USB wifi adapter" will work by plugging into the USB port (instead of an adapter that plugs into the ethernet port).  Thanks.  (I think of something I plug into a port -- instead of replacing a card inside -- as an "external device" but I see the confusion.)  THANKS!

Comment: The device is called a Ethernet to WiFi bridge. They are more expensive than USB dongles though